# program hangs up when ran on similar machine

Tags: terminal, mojave

I am running a computational biology program NUPACK, with the same input, on two slightly different Macbooks Pro:

- First is 10.14, 2017 13-inch, 2.5 GHz Intel Core i7, 16 GB 2133 MHz LPDDR3. the program uses 99.9% CPU, 1 thread and 7MB RAM, runs in 26 sec. 8MB real memory, 6MB private memory
- Second is 10.14.1, 2018 15-inch with magic bar, 2.6 GHz Intel Core i7, 32GB RAM 2400 MHz DDR4. This one couldn't even finish running script in 20 minutes, hence it is at least 60x slower. Program uses 1 thread, 99%CPU, 2MB real memory, 800KB private memory

The program is CMake-compiled (cmake installed via homebrew). The one different thing is that on second machine, user first tried to install CMake from the precompiled binary, but then I installed via `homebrew`. I have reinstalled `homebrew` and `CMake`, and re-compiled the program.

On both machines the program runs OK with no parameters or with bad parameters (throws error/help info), so it is probably not a compilation error. The installation process was identical and no special flags/modifiers were used.

On both systems input file sits on local filesystem (SSD), in Downloads folder. Both have APFS (Encrypted) filesystem. I run programs using root user (but not `sudo ...`)

What can I do to troubleshoot this further? Both laptops run in very similar software environment (University-purchased laptops with Sophos anti-virus) and I can see very little differences between two.

Program is not in Sandbox on both computers

**Update** with data from sampling process:

[Success](https://gist.github.com/aandreev0/e339760950aa78d7131fa4af2c2895aa) and [Failed run](https://gist.github.com/aandreev0/f4a41961fee1899bdfbf40c2d6f398e9)

One thing that seems important are these errors:

```
+ 51 fgets  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 42  [0x7fff631ed7ec]
                                    + ! 27 flockfile  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 31  [0x7fff631ece6c]
                                    + ! : 14 _pthread_mutex_lock_init_slow  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 37  [0x7fff633561f9]
                                    + ! : | 14 _pthread_mutex_check_init_slow  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 21,4,...  [0x7fff6335623d,0x7fff6335622c,...]
                                    + ! : 7 pthread_mutex_lock  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 0,120  [0x7fff6335614b,0x7fff633561c3]
                                    + ! : 6 _pthread_mutex_lock_init_slow  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 42,6,...  [0x7fff633561fe,0x7fff633561da,...]
                                    + ! 7 flockfile  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 36  [0x7fff631ece71]
                                    + ! : 7 __error  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 0,23  [0x7fff6329f55d,0x7fff6329f574]
                                    + ! 7 flockfile  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 10,42,...  [0x7fff631ece57,0x7fff631ece77,...]
                                    + ! 5 DYLD-STUB$$__error  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 0  [0x7fff63233218]
                                    + ! 5 flockfile  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 15  [0x7fff631ece5c]
                                    + !   5 __error  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 0,23  [0x7fff6329f55d,0x7fff6329f574]
```

What does this error mean? Can I use it to debug?

```
 + ! 3 funlockfile  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 15  [0x7fff631ecec4]
 + !   3 __error  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 23,0  [0x7fff6329f574,0x7fff6329f55d]
```

**Update 2**

Interesting observation: on the second machine (FAIL) I can't make the program run as `sudo program file_name`. It never start the program process!

Comment: Do you mean a 2.6GHz _Core_ i7? I'm being picky here. I would look at why the 2018 MBP is using far less memory than the 2017 MBP.

Comment: Is it running in Sandboxed mode  on 2018 Mac? Open Activity Monitor, add Sandbox to the menu bar

Comment: @Buscar웃 both are not

Comment: thank you, back to Activity Monitor, compare the 2 Macs for the same app, from number of treads open, to running a `Sample Process` report. Compare the results.

Comment: @Buscar웃 # of threads is the same = 1. I did peek into Sample process tab, but not sure what to look for. From what I see, the 2nd laptop seems to be stuck at certain step of the program. I am not familiar with Sample Process thing at all to know what to look for

Comment: OK, post that info of interest so we can take look (do not dump all of it)

Comment: How was the initial attempt to install cmake done, exactly?  What were the configure vars like directory installed to, etc?  I would start there, in the source dir of the initial compile attempt, and grep any makefile for an uninstall or remove directive, and the execute that before blowing away the source dir and uninstalling and cleaning the homebrew version as well.  Then reinstall homebrew version.

Comment: CMake in itself probably has nothing to do with the slow down. CMake does not compile your program and it doesn't produce the binary. The purpose of CMake is simply to create the Makefile. That file is in turn used by a program called make to orchestrate the actual compiler(s) and linker(s) that produce the binary.

Comment: @jksoegaard thanks for clarification. I thought that CMake is probably not at fault here. But will try to start from clean slate.

Comment: @Buscar웃 updated with dump of Sample and an `funlockfile` and `__srefill0 ` errors observation

Comment: @aaaaaa The input files for the computation - where are they stored? (detail for both computers) - i.e. is it local storage, network storage, SSD/HDD, file system, etc.

Comment: @aaaaaa You'll need to be more specific according to the questions I asked in order to get some meaningful out of it.

Comment: @jksoegaard sorry, added to the Q. Everything seems identical. On both systems input file sits on local filesystem (SSD), in Downloads folder. Both have APFS (Encrypted) filesystem. I run programs using root user (but not sudo ...)